# Texture problems with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]

[image]

FILE (less than 2 mb): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WA3w3Ge7d9dcQu06PUIzS4RqcgHRcGqf/view?usp=sharing

I've created this road generator with geometry nodes that takes **mesh lines and vertexes as input,** then outputs this road. The number of lanes can be changed.

One thing I can't figure out is **how to make the texture "even" everywhere**. No matter what I do, it is reliant on each "leg" of the road structure. So as you can see in the first image, the short road segment has very short white dotted lines, while the longer road sections have sparse ones.

Any ideas how to do this? I tried to use Curve Resample node but couldn't get it to work. Tried multiple approaches, couldn't get any of them to work.

Comment: it might help if you "resample curve" after "mesh to curve"

Comment: I tried resampling the curve, but at least personally, I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

[image]

result:

[image]

GN modifier:

[image]

material:

[image]

Important is: multiply the factor with the length so that the texture is looking the same independent of the curve length. Capture attribute to save the uv coordinate in the group output, fill the variable in the modifier to use this in the shader nodes as uv coordinate. The two multiplayer nodes are just in there to finetune the uv coordinates that it looks good.

> Note: you didn't pack resource before uploading your blend file so your road texture wasn't in your blend file. So i had to use another texture (i used checker so you can see it works)

UPDATE:

it is exactly the same principle:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: that looks great! I should have specified that I'm looking to do this with the object "Roads 2 (Boolean Roads)", but I think this technique will apply there as well.

However, I can't get it to work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WA3w3Ge7d9dcQu06PUIzS4RqcgHRcGqf/view?usp=sharing

This should be the same as your updated node tree, but I am doing something wrong. It's all just a single color, and I don't know why. I've now packed the texture in the blend file as well. I couldn't get the checker texture working either.

Comment: it is the same principle....i updated my answer.

Comment: hey this is really great and I am thankful. Can you please take a look at the second file and see why my checkerboard texture is not working? I honestly cannot figure out what I did wrong with the node tree and/or shader. (I am now talking about the highway)

EDIT: I got the regular road working just fine with your geometry nodes image, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the highway.

Comment: you forgot to name the attribute in your modifier. And check your node setup. They are not as i showed you in the solution. Try first exactly rebuild my solution. And check whether it works. Then try to modify it. Don't modify in the beginning because that's only frustrating if you don't understood it completely.

Comment: that link is wrong, just delete it and name the attribute in your GN modifier   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/420zU.png

Comment: I spotted one mistake in the geometry nodes (one of the multiply nodes was wrong, should be correct now). But sorry, I do not understand "name the attribute" in this context. I thought I did that with "Highway Road" (the one you named "uv")? Do you mean something else?

Comment: in the modifier: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soN0O.png

Comment: sorry for being this dense, but I don't understand. Name it how? My modifier stack looks exactly the same as yours in that screenshot. I tried using all of the options it gives for me but none of them work for the texture.

Comment: Enter the name of your attribute there

Comment: Read my solution: it says „uv“ in the output attributes of the modifier- your field is empty

Comment: AAAHHHH RIGHT, yeah it works perfectly now. Thank you so much. This is most definitely 100% answered now.

Comment: sure, what's the easiest way to do that?